# What characteristics do Alpha/Beta wolves have in the Twilight series?

Tags: werewolf, twilight

I watched *Breaking Dawn Part One*, where they used the term Alpha Wolf for their leader. But how can one become an Alpha wolf in the Twilight series, and what are the differences between the Alpha and Beta wolves? It doesn't get explained or maybe I missed something. Is this explained in *Breaking Dawn Part Two* or the novels etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Twilight, the leader of the tribe is the *[Alpha](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Pack_structure#Alpha) Wolf*.

The second in command is referred to (by Bella, not the shifters themselves) as the [*Beta*](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Pack_structure#Beta) Wolf.

**How can become a Alpha wolf?**

Either by election, or by lineage.

**Alpha Powers**

The main power an Alpha gets is the "[Alpha Voice](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Pack_structure#Alpha_voice)".

> The Alpha voice is an ability that only a genetic or elected Alpha
>   shape-shifter possesses. It is unknown how the Alpha voice works and
>   whether an Alpha shape-shifter can use his Alpha voice to command his
>   pack members in both human and wolf forms. Once an Alpha shape-shifter
>   gives orders to members of his pack, his orders are obeyed blindly.
>   The pack members cannot directly disobey commands even if they are in
>   disagreement. This ability, however, is limited to pack member and
>   cannot influence another Alpha shape-shifter.

The Beta Wolf can also do this, but can be overruled by the Alpha.

In addition an Alpha can also communicate with the Alphas of another pack telepapthically (like how they can within their own pack).

Comment: The "Beta" wolf (the "first") cannot force others to obey their commands like the Alpha can, unless the Alpha's command is to obey the Beta's command (then really the Alpha is just confirming that command). Other than a general desire among the group for a chain of command (which wasn't really needed until the pack grew to almost two dozen wolves) the commands of more "senior" wolves only carried weight equal to the "junior" wolf's respect for the senior.